# MySQL delete all results of sub-query

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, sql-delete

Okay, so if you would like a back story, look at my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392012/showing-all-duplicates-side-by-side-in-mysql/)

Figuring out which of my records is not a duplicate is quite easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM eventlog
GROUP BY event_date, user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY event_date, user
```

This returns all of my non-duplicates. So I thought I'd move them over to another table called "no_duplicates" and then delete them from the original table. Then I could see the duplicates all alone in the original table, fix them up, and add the no_dupes back. But while:

```
INSERT INTO no_duplicates
SELECT *
FROM eventlog
GROUP BY event_date, user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY event_date, user
```

Works like a charm, the following throws an error:

```
DELETE
FROM eventlog
GROUP BY event_date, user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY event_date, user
```

My guess is that while the query returns unique, already-in-the-table records, deleting by a aggregate function isn't kosher. Which is understandable except I don't know what else I can do to secure that only the records I moved are deleted. I searched and found no "After INSERT kill the records in the original table" syntax, and my guess is that it would fail anyway, for the same reason the delete failed.

So, can someone help me find the missing piece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need the ORDER BY on the INSERT and DELETE. It's just useful if you need them for presentation which is not the case with those operations.

If your EVENTLOG table has a primary key (like ID) you could form your DELETE-statement like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM eventlog
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT *
  FROM eventlog
  GROUP BY event_date, user
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not delete with the aggregate function. I think you would like to delete all the inserted data ?

Why not try something like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM eventlog
WHERE (user, event_date) IN (SELECT user, event_data FROM no_duplicates)
```

Comment: So, to be clear. putting the `WHERE` clause in parenthesis means that both the user and the event date need to be in the specific row of the no_duplicates table? Because obviously the users and event_dates repeat independently throughout both.
Okay, I hate to sound rushed or incompetent, so please forgive me. I'm really anxious because rebuilding this will take even more time and make people even more annoyed with me. I hate deadlines.

Comment: Yes - but to be 100% sure - always backup before trying statements

Comment: So this means the statement deletes all the rows where the user AND event_date is the same than in the row from the no_duplicates.
I think this is what you want ?
Otherwise you would have to specifiy a better key (id ?)

Comment: another tip - if you want to test out if a delete statement is working - use the where clause with a "select *". Then you see all the rows which are going to be deleted. [Maybe there are some edge cases where this statement wouldn't work - but I can't think of any)

Comment: Actually, instead of deleting them, I simply did a `SELECT` so that only the duplicates showed up (basically, `SELECT * FROM eventlog WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM duplicates)`. Turns out having keys was handy in so many obvious ways. Knock on head.

Comment: That multiple field syntax was a real life saver for me. thx.

Comment: Yeah the multiple field syntax is handy.

Answer (score 4):

What's the database? If MySQL then

> Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

At least for 5.0 version. ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html )

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [DELETE syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_(SQL)), there are neither GROUP BYs, nor HAVINGs, nor ORDERs.

Comment: Sorry, I was grabbing everything as efficiently as I could. I know ORDERS are not necessary for deleting things. And I quickly learned that GROUP BY's and HAVINGs are out, hence the question.

Comment: ORDERs are not **allowed** in DELETEs (apart from being pointless)

Comment: `ORDER` absolutely *is* allowed in `DELETE` in MySQL. [And has been for a very, very long time.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html) *"If the DELETE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, rows are deleted in the order specified by the clause. This is useful primarily in conjunction with LIMIT. ... ORDER BY may also be useful in some cases to delete rows in an order required to avoid referential integrity violations. ORDER BY can be used with DELETE beginning with MySQL 4.0.0."*

Answer (score -1):

You may try adding a primary key auto increment column, move your uniques into a new table and do a delete eventlog.* from eventlog e inner join no_dupes nd on e.id=nd.id